# How much of the Black God (Kurokami) manga was adapted into the anime?

Tags: black-god

How much of the Black God (Kurokami) manga was adapted into the anime, as in up to what chapter/volume?

> Most humans do not know that every person is one of three doppel liners, three people who share the same fate, and that god-like beings called mototsumitama protect the natural balance of power in the world. However, Keita Ibuki, a videogame programmer from Tokyo, is suddenly drawn into the intrigues of the mototsumitama during a chance encounter with Kuro, a young mototsumitama who makes a contract with Keita in order to save his life. Along with Keita's childhood friend Akane Sano, the pair begins to investigate strange disruptions in the natural balance of power that seem to be connected to a powerful clan of mototsumitama.
>    - http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=10262

The ending of the anime:

> Akane is getting married to Keita, and thanks Kuro for allowing them to reach that point. Several decades later, Kuro receives a telepathic message from a very old Keita. He tells her that he will take the curse with him, thanking her for giving him a happy life. Keita died afterward just before his grandchildren come to get him for dinner. A relieved Kuro then tells her beloved Contractee to rest in peace. -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kurokami:_The_Animation_episodes

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for. But having seen the first episode of the series, I can say that the divergence begins in Chapter 1/episode 1 as Keita's character is completely changed. In the manga he programs video games while in the anime he is a high-schooler. In the manga he is an arrogant prick; no such attributes to the anime character.

Since the anime was produced when the manga was still being written, the anime had to *completely* diverge from the manga's plot at one point. This, I'm told, happened in episode 12. I'm not entirely sure which chapter or volume this represents. The ending is completely different from the manga.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for then is how much material the anime covered up to episode 12.

Comment: @ton.yeung FWIW, the gist of my answer is that if you are asking this question in order to skip chapters covered in the anime, then my answer is "Don't skip anything and read from the beginning".